# If a relation is euclidean, is it necessarily asymmetric?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

$R$ is relation on set $A$, that is $R\subseteq A \times A $. $R$ is euclidean if $(\forall x,y,z\in A)(xRy\land xRz \Rightarrow yRz)$. $R$ is asymmetric if $(\forall x,y\in A)(xRy\Rightarrow \lnot(yRx)).$

For example, if R euclidean relation on A, and $(1,2)\in R$, then because $R$ euclidean and $(1,2), (1,2)\in R \Rightarrow (2,2)\in R$, which means it isn't asymmetric (because every asymmetric relation is necessarily not reflexive).

But if $R$ is an empty relation, then it's both asymmetric and euclidean, which means an euclidean relation is not necessarily asymmetric. Or am I thinking too much into it?

Comment: What is the euclidean relation?

Comment: @Wuestenfux: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_relation

Comment: @Wuestenfux  I edited the post so that it contains the definitions of euclidean and asymmetric relations now. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: No. From $xRy ∧ xRz$, by commutativity of $\land$ both $yRz$ and $zRy$ follow.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, but isn't an empty relation a relation that is both euclidean and asymmetric?

Comment: What I mean is: An Euclidean relation is not necessarily asymmetric. This means that the def of Euclidean does not imply asymm. We can have "degenerate" case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let R be an Euclidean relation on A. and let $(x,y) \in R $

$xRy \land xRy \Rightarrow yRy $ which means Euclidean relation cant be asymmetric if there exists an $(x,y) \in R$ in case of Empty Relation we know that it doesnt have any elements
so this proposition doesnt contain it